# Get return from onFinalize Firebase cloud function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've created an unzip onFinalize function, which unzip any file which copied to storage, then delete the file, which is working well, but I want to get return from the onFinalize cloud function to my Angular app, or listening somehow to know when finished the process.

Now I use logging, but its annoying, because the rest call to logger api use the accessToken, and its impossible to refresh the accessToken after expired in 3600s *(only if the user logout, and login again its counting again)*

Anyway is there a good solution in Angular without rest call, or without access token?

```
export const manageZipArchives = functions
  .region("xxxxx")
  .runWith({timeoutSeconds: 540, memory: "512MB"})
  .storage.bucket("xxxxxxxxx")
  .object()
  .onFinalize(async (obj: functions.storage.ObjectMetadata) => {
    const file = admin
      .storage()
      .bucket(obj.bucket)
      .file(obj.name!);

    ...

    return ok;
  });
```

Comment: You can't send back response from background functions to client. There's a workaround for that using realtime database but I'm not sure if you are using Firebase SDK as you mentioned REST API.

Comment: Yes, but its very strange, that I can't listening, or get return from function. I thinking about the realtime database too, now I thinking on alternative solutions, but thank your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's very strange, that I can't listening, or get return from function
> (from your comments)

Cloud Functions triggered by Cloud Storage events are **background** Cloud Functions. They don't have any notion of a client (or a frontend): the file created in Cloud Storage could have been created by a backend process, like an app running on a Compute Engine instance for example.

In your case, you can get advantage of the realtime listeners offered by either [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) or the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events).

Let's take the example of a Firestore document. The process would be as follows:

In your Angular app:

1. Generate a document Reference with the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method, in a specific collection.
2. Get the doc ID corresponding to this Reference, with the [`id`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#id) property.
3. Assign this doc ID as a [Custom Metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#custom_metadata) of the file you upload.
4. Set a listener to this document Reference with the [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#onsnapshot) method. The doc does not exist yet, but this is not a problem: when it will be created the listener will be fired.
5. Upload the file

In your Cloud Function:

6. When all the asynchronous work of unziping, deletion, etc... is complete, get the value of the document ID stored as a Custom Metadata value and create the document in Firestore => The listener in the angular app will be triggered and you know that the work for this file is complete.

Note that if you want to report a potential error or exception to the frontend you could also use the Firestore doc: for example you can add a `status` field and an `errorMessage` field with the desired info. In the listener you'll get the value of those fields.